# Get-Member Stops PowerShell Pipelines

Tags: powershell

When piping a collection of objects, the results of `gm` and `% { $_ | gm }` are different.  How is this difference described?

For example, we define two custom objects `$a` and `$b`:

```
PS C:\> $a = [PSCustomObject]@{p=1; q=2}
PS C:\> $b = [PSCustomObject]@{r=3; s=4}
```

When piping them to `gm`, we somehow get properties of only `$a`:

```
PS C:\> $a, $b | gm -MemberType NoteProperty | % { $_.Name }
p
q
```

When piping them to `% { $_ | gm }`, we get properties of `$a` and `$b` as expected:

```
PS C:\> $a, $b | % { $_ | gm -MemberType NoteProperty } | % { $_.Name }
p
q
r
s
```

Comment: `Get-Member` get members only of first object for same `TypeName`.

Comment: @PetSerAl  Thank you for your quick reply!  `Get-Member` seems to work as you say.

Comment: I can not know why it behave that way, I can only guess. I think, it optimized for general use case like `ps|gm` or `dir|gm`. Should `ps|gm` produce copies of information about `System.Diagnostics.Process`? Normally, objects with same `TypeName` have same members, so `Get-Member` print this information only once for each `TypeName`.

Answer (score 0):

Get-Member (and Powershell) appears to get a bit confused when objects of the same type in an array don't have matching properties:

```
PS C:\> $a, $b | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
p           NoteProperty int p=1                       
q           NoteProperty int q=2                       

PS C:\> $a, $b

p q
- -
1 2

PS C:\> $a, $b | Select-Object -Property p, q, r, s

p q r s
- - - -
1 2
    3 4
```

My guess is that `Get-Member` iterates over each type and only outputs each type once.  For example, `1, (Get-Date), 2 | gm` only outputs one instance of `System.Int32`.

Compare the output of the last two lines:

```
[int32]$c = 1;
[int32]$d = 2;

$d | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Test' -Value $true -Force;

$c, $d | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty;

$d, $c | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty;
```

Comment: IMHO, it would be more clearly if you use `TypeName` change: `$a=[PSCustomObject]@{}; $a,1|Get-Member`, `$a.PSTypeNames.Insert(0,'System.Int32'); $a,1|Get-Member`.

Comment: @Bacon Bits @PetSerAl  Thank you for your reply!  I understood the behavior of `Get-Member`.  But I still don't know when this behavior is useful.